# React-router-dom and state

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a little react app which uses the react-router-dom. Then I have three different components viz. incomes, edit-income, and add-income. **Incomes** is the first page which displays incomes (and other details like invoice number, date added, title, description) in a table form. Each row of an income has an edit and delete button. On clicking the edit button of an income, the **edit-income**page is loaded so I can edit the details and save changes which will reflect on my **Incomes** page. The same concept is applied to the **add-income** page which is the third page to add a new income to those on the **Income** page.

Please can someone show me the best way to share data between those three components (incomes, add-income, edit-income) without losing the data stored in my "state" object anytime any of my components is rendered.

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './fonts/css/all.css';
import './App.css';


let Context = React.createContext();

class Provider extends Component {
state = [
  { title: 'Fees', category: 'tuition', amount: 300, invNum: '001', date: 
  '23-03-99', note: 'My Payment' },
  { title: 'SRC', category: 'tuition', amount: 400, invNum: '002', date: 
  '26-06-99', note: 'My Dues' },
  { title: 'PTA', category: 'tuition', amount: 500, invNum: '003', date: 
  '29-09-99', note: 'My Check' }
]


render() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{
       state: this.state,


    delInc: (e) => {
      let target = e.target.closest('tr');
      console.log(target);
      let parent = document.querySelector('.table-row');
      let arrParent = Array.from(parent.children);
      let index = arrParent.findIndex(index => index === target);
      let state = this.state.splice(index, 1);

      if (this.state.length === 0) {
        document.querySelector('#display').style.display = 'block';
      }
    },


    addInc: () => {

      let state = [...state, {
        title: 'Mass', category: 'tuition', amount: 500, invNum: '003', 
        date: '29-09-99', note: 'My Check'
      }];
      console.log(state);
      this.setState({ state });
    }  
  }}>
    {this.props.children}
  </Context.Provider>
)
}

}


/**** INCOME COMPONENT */
function Income({ index, income }) {

  return (
    <Context.Consumer>
      {(c) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <td className="title">{c.state[index].title}</td>
          <td className="category">{c.state[index].category}</td>
          <td className="amnt">{c.state[index].amount}</td>
          <td className="invc-num">{c.state[index].invNum}</td>
          <td className="date">{c.state[index].date}</td>
          <td className="note">{c.state[index].note}</td>
          <td className="action">
          <a href="/edit" id="edit-bttn">
            <i className="fa fa-pen-nib"></i>
          </a>

          <a href="#!" id="del-bttn" onClick={c.delInc}>
            <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
          </td>
      </React.Fragment>
     )}
   </Context.Consumer>

  );
 }

/** INCOMES COMPONENT */
function Incomes() {

return (
  <Context.Consumer>
    {(c) => (

      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="income-header" onLoad={c.addInc()}>
          <i className="fa fa-coins"></i>
          <span className="hero-txt"> Income</span>
        </div>

        <a href="/add" id="add-inc-bttn">
          <i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Income
        </a>

        <div id="display">No Incomes to Display</div>

        <table>
          <tr className="header-row">
            <th className="title">Title</th>
            <th className="category">Category</th>
            <th className="amnt">Amount</th>
            <th className="invc-num">Invoice No.</th>
            <th className="date">Date</th>
            <th className="note">Note</th>
            <th className="action">Action</th>
          </tr>

        <Context.Consumer>
          {(c) => (
            <>
              <tbody className="table-row">
                {c.state.map((income, index) => (
                  <tr>
                    <Income
                      key={index}
                      income={income}
                      index={index}
                    />
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </>
          )}

        </Context.Consumer>
      </table>

    </React.Fragment>)}
</Context.Consumer>
)
}

function Edit() {

return (
  <Context.Consumer>
    {(c) => (
      <>
        <div className="edit-box">
        <div id="edit-header">
          <i className="fa fa-pen"></i>
          <span className="hero-txt"> Edit Income</span>
        </div>

        <a href="/incomes" id="view-bttn">
          <i className="fa fa-eye"></i> View all
        </a>

        <h3 id="prompt">
          <i className="fa fa-check-double"></i> Income Updated successfully!
        </h3>

        <div className="edit-frame">
          <div className="row-1">
            <div id="title">
              <label className="label">
                <span>*</span> Title
          </label>
              <input type="text" size="60" />
            </div>

            <div id="category">
              <label>
                <span>*</span> Category
          </label>

              <select className="select">
                <option>One</option>
                <option>Two</option>
                <option>Three</option>
                <option>Four</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="row-2">
            <div id="uniform">
              <label>School uniform</label>
              <input type="text" size="35" />
            </div>

            <div id="invc">
              <label>Invoice Number</label>
              <input type="text" size="35" />
            </div>

            <div id="date">
              <label>
                <span>*</span> Income date
          </label>
              <input type="date" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Note:</label>
            <textarea className="notes" cols="120" rows="5">
              Note
        </textarea>
          </div>

          <div className="add-box">
            <a href="#" className="add-inc-btn">
                Add New Income <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )}
</Context.Consumer>

  );
}


function Add() {
  return (
    <Context.Consumer>
       {(c) => (
         <div className="edit-box">
         <div id="edit-header">
           <i className="fa fa-pen"></i>
           <span className="hero-txt"> Add New Income</span>
         </div>

         <a href="/incomes" id="view-bttn">
           <i className="fa fa-eye"></i> View all
         </a>

         <h3 id="prompt">
           <i className="fa fa-check-double"></i> Income added successfully !
         </h3>

      <div className="edit-frame">
        <div className="row-1">
          <div id="title">
            <label className="label">
              <span>*</span> Title
          </label>
            <input type="text" size="60" />
          </div>

          <div id="category">
            <label>
              <span>*</span> Category
          </label>

            <select className="select">
              <option>One</option>
              <option>Two</option>
              <option>Three</option>
              <option>Four</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row-2">
          <div id="uniform">
            <label>School uniform</label>
            <input type="text" size="35" />
          </div>

          <div id="invc">
            <label>Invoice Number</label>
            <input type="text" size="35" />
          </div>

          <div id="date">
            <label>
              <span>*</span> Income date
          </label>
            <input type="date" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Note:</label>
          <textarea
            className="notes"
            cols="120"
            rows="5"
            placeholder="Type Here..."
            defaultValue="Note"
          >
          </textarea>
        </div>

        <div className="add-box">
          <a href="#!" className="add-inc-btn" onClick={c.addInc}>
            Add New Income <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      )}
    </Context.Consumer>
  );
}


 /**** APP COMPONENT */
class App extends Component {

render() {
   return (
     <Provider>
        <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/incomes" component={Incomes} />
          <Route path="/add" component={Add} />
          <Route path="/edit" component={Edit} />
          </Switch>
       </Router>
       </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You could look into `react context` or go full blown `redux` for your state management needs.

Comment: Some more information with what you are trying to achieve with code sample would be nice, thanks.

Comment: @Danyal You got it

Answer (score 0):

if you share your code, we'll get better. But you can check this out, it simply gives an idea of how to share data between components.

https://dev.to/dipakkr/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-other-component-in-react-35i2

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here but I would go with what Huseyin is suggesting, though, you should know what options you have.

- Prop Drilling

You can go a long way by using your parent component (in this case "Income") as the single source of truth for your data, and pass around the data and the functions that mutate it in the form of props. It is the most basic way of getting things done around in react and if your app is never going to go beyong 3-4 components, you should just use it because it's the easiest, require no boilerplate, and it's a good starting point for understanding why you need other state management tools.

ref: [React State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
ref: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

- React Context

Comes with React, easy to use global state object that you can instantiate one state object to and it will become the single source of truth. The code required for this is minimal and you don't have to pass props around as your app becomes a little more complex and you won't have the problem of your state getting mingled and stale in one component just because you forgot to update the props properly.

ref: [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

- Redux/MobX

Redux/MobX are great for apps which have dozens of components where some of them can be far away from each and need access to state. Doing this kind of thing with passing props would create a huge mess, doing this with context is possible but in the end you'll be creating your own redux. It grants you access to a large amount of tooling like Redux Devtools, and some specific libraries that target it like Redux Thunks and Sagas which can be used for async handling. Using it in a small app is likely overkill so just try to stick to first two and learn Redux for fun and because it's required in most of the industry.